# Firebase Analytics multiple table events

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase Analytics to send some custom information from inside of the app iOS and android app. For some reason, when i see the values inside of Google BigQuery, I see the data was pushed twice so I have too many repetitive values. How could I stop it from doing that? On iOS, I will sometimes see it posted 3 or 4 times. Here is a quick snippet from the android side:

```
 mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("user_email", user.getEmail());
 mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("location", locationValue);
```

Comment: Please post a bit more code. Specifically the stuff around it so that we can check for loops or methods that could be called more than once.

Comment: Also, personal information, especially location data and email should not be saved to Firebase Analytics as per their terms of service and privacy policy.

Comment: The code around that may be the only cause of it recursing is a addListenerForSingleValueEvent but that won't run more than once.That's the confusing part. On iOS, I have the equivalent and it will make 2 or 3 duplicates. On Android, it will show some data once (as it should) but will occasionally have duplicates (like half the time)

Answer (score 0):

When you set user property the **value is persisted and uploaded with every subsequent data upload**. If you like to record something that happens at given moment in time you should log an event.

See [Set User Property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#setUserProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) documentation for more details.